# Google translation API for a Chrome extension

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I am in the middle of creating a simple/quick translator that just translated selected words on the fly, i would like to release it as a free extension, is there anyway i can use Google translation API without having to pay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use google translation API without Billing, beside you can try to create extension that takes selected word and translating it using traslate.google.com by generating a translation url for example:
http://translate.google.com/#en|ru|hello
Will translate word hello from English to Russian,
Or you can think about to open that URL from serverside using for example some CURL script and get the content from result box and send the result VIA ajax to your extension.

Comment: perform a request and get the results using cURL is legal?